# Unclear behavior of FlowOps.delay

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I am trying to understand the `FlowOps.delay` method by experimenting with the code for two days and there is some point I evidently miss.

So let's consider the following code:

```
val source = Source(1 to 100)
val flow = Flow[Int].delay(4 second, DelayOverflowStrategy.dropHead)
val sink = Sink.foreach(println)

source
  .via(flow)
  .to(sink)
  .run
```

I have expected it to wait 4 seconds and then print las 16 numbers from the `(1 to 100)` sequence. And it behaved accordingly and after 4 seconds delay it printed numbers from 85 till 100.

Now if I change the overflow strategy to `dropTail` it also behaves appropriately and prints numbers from 1, ..., 15, 100.

That's all fine.

Now comes the overflow strategy `dropNew` and the following

```
val source = Source(1 to 100)
val flow = Flow[Int].delay(4 second, DelayOverflowStrategy.dropNew)
val sink = Sink.foreach(println)

source
  .via(flow)
  .to(sink)
  .run
```

produces output that I don't understand at all. It waits 4 seconds, then prints 1,2. Then wait 4 seconds and prints 3,4. Waits 4 seconds and prints 5,6. And so on.

QUESTION1: why `dropNew` behaves in this way? I expected to see 4 seconds delay and then numbers from 1 to 16 printed immediately.

QUESTION2: if I set overflow strategy to `backpressure` it behaves completely the same way as `dropNew`. Why? Based on my understanding while delay is in progress it should consume first 16 elements (because 16 is the default buffer size) and then backpressure the source. Then when the delay passed it should emmit the head of the buffer, the number 1, then again delay and it consumes just one more element and backpressures and then just repeats in cycles. So I expected actually to see elements printed each 4 seconds and by one element.